# how to use hibernate as the datasource within the JTablemodel

Tags: hibernate

I would like to do something similar to the following (which is using jdbc as the datasource in the table model) but with hibernate.
How do I go about it please?
Thanks

```
  // Table Model
    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    Connection myConnect; // Hold the JDBC Connection
    Statement myStatement; // Will contain the SQL statement
    ResultSet myResultSet; // Contains the result of my SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    Session mySession; // Hibernate Session, used to run queries
    String myHQL; // Will contain the HQL statement
    List<?> myResult; // Contains the result of my HQL statement
```

Hope I could understand you question.